# QBFC WCF Service Error

Tags: vb.net, intuit-partner-platform, qbfc

I have a new blank Wcf Service in vs.net 2013 express. I have added the reference to the qbfc12.dll and did the import Imports QBFC12Lib. I run the blank wcf service and it works fine. I then add one line of code and it breaks and gives me a error.

Function that works fine:

```
Public Function GetData(ByVal value As Integer) As String Implements IService1.GetData
    Return String.Format("You entered: {0}", value)
End Function
```

Function that gives exception(One line of code added only):

```
Public Function GetData(ByVal value As Integer) As String Implements IService1.GetData
    Dim SessionManager As New QBSessionManager
    Return String.Format("You entered: {0}", value)
End Function
```

I get the following exception on that line:

> An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {C693D8F1-180B-4F82-B735-8F511B566718} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

Can anyone please help me? I have a wcf server written on my laptop, that runs perfect. I am only trying to move it to my production server, but does not work. So removed all the code down to this one line of code that is giving the issue, but it all worked fine on my laptop.

Comment: Well I got past that, it was in advanced settings of the App Pool to allow 32 bit applications. Now I can not get it to open the company file. The Wcf Service keeps erroring out trying to do a BeginSession. I think it may be a security issue, but I cannot get past it so far. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: What error is `BeginSession` throwing? Have you installed the QBSDK on the production server?

Answer (score 1):

The QBFC12 installer needs to be run on the machine your application is executing from. It is available for download in the link below. You have to sign up to download the installer, but there's no cost and you don't even have to verify your email.

Page with all installers:
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0200_quickbooks_desktop/0400_tools/quickbooks_desktop/download_the_sdk

Installer in question:
QBFC12_Installer (Version 12.0.0.29)
https://developer.intuit.com/Downloads/Restricted?filename=qbfc12_0installer.exe